# Name of irregular convex octahedron

Tags: symmetry, polyhedra, polytopes

I wonder about the name of the following irregular convex octahedron:

- You can create it by taking a regular pentagon on the xy plane, and
  then duplicating one vertex, and changing the z coordinate of this
  two vertices, sending one vertex up and one vertex down by the same length.
- Or you can think of it as the [Convex hull of this points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pvbbj.png)

The final polyhedra will have 6 vertex, 12 edges, 8 faces and it will be convex.  I hope there is a name for it since it has very specific symmetries.

Answer (score 0):

It is an example of a [biaugmented tetrahedron](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Biaugmented_tetrahedron.png). Wolfram MathWorld calls it a [boat](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Boat.html).
(These links show images of a topologically equivalent polyhedron with all equilateral triangles, but which is not convex; your octahedron is convex but consists of non-equilateral triangles. MathWorld includes a picture of a convex "boat" on the page [Octahedron](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Octahedron.html), but it doesn't have the same symmetry as your construction.)

It is one of only two convex polyhedra with 8 faces and 6 vertices (as you can see at [Counting Polyhedra](http://www.numericana.com/data/polyhedra.htm)). Three possible Schlegel diagrams were given on [Steven Dutch's Enumeration of Polyhedra page](https://web.archive.org/web/20141117072140/http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/symmetry/poly8f0.htm):

[image]

Its dual is this guy:

[image]

which can be called a *pentagonal wedge*.