# What is the name of this irregular 8-faced convex polyhedron?

Tags: geometry, terminology, polyhedra

I am trying to find the name of a polyhedron visually similar to the [ditrigonal trapezoprism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_prism#Symmetry) but with a distortion reducing its symmetry.

Here is an image of the polyhedron I am referring to:

[image]

The polyhedron is formed by two similar parallel [ditrigonal](https://polytope.miraheze.org/wiki/Ditrigon) faces rotated by 60°, joined by six trapezoids, just like the ditrigonal trapezoprism. However, the two ditrigons have different sizes, resulting in the six trapezoidal faces to split into two sets of three identical trapezoids. This reduces the symmetry from D<sub>3d</sub> to C<sub>3v</sub>.

I already considered two different names:

- **Ditrigonal trapezoprism frustum** because of its similarity with the hexagonal frustum. This is not suitable, though, because a ditrigonal frustum has a different symmetry.
- **Ditrigonal trapezofrustum** could make sense, but I have not found any use of the word "trapezofrustum". This would come from the similarity between the distortion of a *hexagonal prism* into a *hexagonal frustum* and the distortion of a *ditrigonal trapezoprism* into a *ditrigonal "trapezofrustum"*.

(edit) Following [Jean Marie's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765869/what-is-the-name-of-this-irregular-8-faced-convex-polyhedron#comment7749103_3765869), one notices that comparable polyhedra to the one I describe can be obtained by cutting a trigonal antiprism at two planes parallel to the base face. To obtain the unnamed polyhedron I described above, we are restrained in two ways when following this cutting process. First, the base and top faces of the (now distorted) trigonal antiprism need to be of different sizes, otherwise, top and bottom facets both similar and of different sizes cannot be cut. Second, cuts through two random planes will, in general, lead to two *non-similar* ditrigonal faces. The two cuts can thus not be independent. This leads to new questions that could help us answer the original one: (1) "What is the name of an antiprism with different-sized similar top and bottom faces?" and (2) "Is there a name for such a specific cutting process as I described?"

I already looked at Wikipedia's [list of small polyhedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_polyhedra_by_vertex_count) and its [list of polygons, polyhedra and polytopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_polygons,_polyhedra_and_polytopes) as well as [other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2669692/name-of-irregular-convex-octahedron) similar [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3134638/names-for-polyhedra#comment6458185_3134638) without ever encountering this polyhedron. It appears from [Vasily Mitch's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3134638/names-for-polyhedra#comment6458185_3134638) that not all polyhedra have names. What is the name of this polyhedron if it has one? Is there another way I can find it out? If it does not have a name, what should we call it?

Comment: I would call it a "truncated hexagonal antiprism" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_antiprism)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it leads us further towards naming the polyhedron. I edited my question to take your idea into consideration.

Comment: How about "Helen"?

Comment: I'd opt for either "truncated _trigonal_ antiprism" or "drunk hexagonal prism".

Comment: @IvanNeretin (+1) to the idea of any kind of "drunk" object.

Comment: @Xander Henderson I don't understand your reference to "Helen" proposal. Could you explain ? Is it a pun ?

Comment: @JeanMarie The question asks us to name the polyhedron.  I think a that Helen is a nice name.  In more words:  I don't think that it really matters what you call the object---one name is as good as another.  If describing the object is important, then whatever name you choose will probably catch on.  If it is not important, or doesn't have general applications, then it doesn't really matter what you call it, anyhow.